# Obtaining the Fundamental Polygon of $\mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space, spheres

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon) page, Wikipedia shows, under the "Examples" heading, the fundamental polygons of the Sphere and the Real Projective Plane. Can we obtain the latter diagram from the former? I thought that this might be possible since $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is defined as the quotient of the sphere under the equivalence relation that identifies antipodal points, but I couldn't find a way to make it work. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to convince yourself the diagram below represents the antipodal map, with the shaded triangle as fundamental domain.

[image: Antipodal identification of a sphere gives a projective plane]

On the subject, there's a nice way to visualize antipodal identification of a [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) (a polyhedral model of a sphere) yielding a [tetrahemihexahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahemihexahedron) (a polyhedral model of a real projective plane).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!